# Norris exercise: Showing $P_0[\text{no return to}\ 0]=6/\pi^2$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider exercise 1.3.4 of Norris' Markov Chains. The question is as follows:

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be a Markov Chain with state space $S=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. Suppose the transition probabilities are given by $$p_{01}=1,\,\,\,p_{i,i+1}+p_{i,i-1}=1, \,\,\,p_{i,i+1}=\dfrac{(i+1)^2}{i^2}p_{i,i-1}$$ for $i\geq1$. Show that $P[X_n\geq1\space\forall n\geq1\mid X_0=0]=\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$

I defined $h_k=P[X_n\neq 0\space\forall n\geq1\mid X_0=k]$ for all $k\geq0$. Note first that $h_0=h_1$ so it is enough to compute $h_1$. I have deduced that for any $k\geq1$, $$h_k=h_1S_k \quad \text{ where }\quad  S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{1}{i^2}$$

I will be done if I can show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}h_k=1$. (And in fact, this will be the case). However, I cannot show it. Intuitively it is clear, but I cannot really show it rigorously.

I noted that $h_k$ are increasing in $k$, so the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}h_k$ exists. But why should this limit be $1$?

Comment: Can anyone lead me in some direction? I am thinking about tail events but $p_k$ are changing due to change in probability measure.

Comment: By the way, I found that Norris "solved" a similar example in the Birth-Death Chain that very same chapter, from which it follows that the value of $h_1=\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$ is the minimal possible solution. I do not understand that Birth-Death example as well, for which I remain inconclusive.

Comment: The usual approach is to compute $h_k^i=P(X\ \text{hits}\ i\ \text{before}\ 0\mid X_0=k)$ for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant i$. These involve a random walk on the finite graph from $0$ to $i$ hence one simply has to solve a linear system of size $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ with boundary conditions $h_0^i=0$ and $h_i^i=1$. The exact formula might be $$h_k^i=\frac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+k^2}{1^2+2^2+\cdots+i^2},$$ but you should check it, then one simply notes that $h_k^i\to h_k$ when $i\to\infty$, which simultaneously explains the results already in your post and answers your question.

Comment: +1 Thanks. This aspect is new to me. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: A better option would be that you connect the dots of the indications in my comment and post the result as an answer.